# How to adjust space between relplot Seaborn subplots for multi-plot layouts

Tags: python, seaborn

I am having a 2 x 1 subplot which is achievable as below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time", data=tips, facet_kws=dict(sharex=False),col_wrap=1)
g.set_xticklabels ( rotation=90, fontsize=18 )


plt.show ()
```

[image]

Currently, I have the issue whereby the x-tick label coincide with  the bottom plot title.

How do I increase the spacing between the plots?

Comment: Apart from the accepted answer, other approach is: `g.fig.subplots_adjust ( wspace=.05, hspace=.3 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the vertical spacing of the graph by using `subplots_adjust()`.

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question has been duplicated, but if you found my answer helpful, you can still accept the answer. Take action before you go on to the next question.

Comment: Unfortunately this OP has been flag for duplicate. While the other two link may solve the issue, but these two OP does not have the keyword `seaborn` nor `relplot`. So, a new seaborn beginner like myself  does not expect the two link might solve this issue thou. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion